# "set --" command to parse output of "ps" command on terminal

Tags: linux, shell, pid, ps

I have trying to get pid of a process using "set --" as following:
say a process is started with command: `java -jar someProg.jar`

In a shell script, i can get the processId using this way:

```
#    
pid_=$(ps -axf | grep  someProg | grep -v grep)

set -- $pid_

echo $1
#
```

Now , I tried to get pid on terminal by writing command as:

```
ps -axf | grep  someProg | grep -v grep | set -- | echo $1
```

But I didn't get anything.

How can i get the output pid using set -- command on terminal.

Thanks

Comment: no need to `set`. http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: `ps` + `grep` = `pgrep`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
ps -axf | grep someProg | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1}'
```

It shows PID of `someProg` process...

Answer (score 1):

You can neither pipe into `set`, because it does not support it, nor use tools like `xargs`, because `set` is a built-in.

This is all you can do:

```
set -- $(ps -axf | grep  someProg | grep -v grep) ; echo $1
```

Btw: you can not pipe into `echo` either.

Comment: Re "*nor use tools like `xargs`*":  there are ways.  For example, `echo foo bar | xargs bash -c 'set -- "$@" ; echo $2' baz`.